# How to set up a Single-Page Application in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, upshot, single-page-application

I've read about Single-Page Applications recently and wanted to try one out. After watching Steve Sanderson's presentation (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159) I wanted to create a Single-Page App in my Visual Studio 2010 and test it out myself. But then I found out I can't choose an SPA template anymore, as it was removed in RC version.

Now, the question is - what should I do in Visual Studio 2010 (with MVC4 installed) to be able to create an SPA? I'd like to use KnockoutJS for UI and Upshot for data, both of which I'm able to install using Nuget. I haven't found anything relevant on the Web, every single page I've been to is telling me to use the SPA template, which has been removed since.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your environment. Steve Sanderson provides instructions how to build SPA here [Single Page Application packages and samples] (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/03/06/single-page-application-packages-and-samples/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is, I can't follow the first step (Choose the Single Page Application subtemplate.), because the SPA subtemplate has been removed in RC version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SPA was excluded from RC because it wasn't ready in time for MVC4 release. [Official ASP.NET SPA page](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application). You can create project with MVC template and scaffold SPA via NuGet ([SPA scaffolding](http://nuget.org/packages/SinglePageApplication))

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it now.

Comment: You also don't need their spa template. You can create a spa on your own, as its just a web app the is contained on a single page.

Comment: Anybody get that Nuget package working? I have it installed, but... nothing. I don't know what to do from here on out. The examples for the SPA project type don't apply. Are there any tutorials out there? Guess I can't showcase it at Code Camp next week :/

Comment: Since he's too humble to say so, I'll say it for him. John Papa has put together a complete training video on how to build a SPA on pluralsight. You should check it out. I would up buying a years subscription to Pluralsight based on his offerings. http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=spa

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2010, try using [Hot Towel](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/) by John Papa.
Create an empty MVC4 app, then install a Nuget from Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package HotTowel
```